# Why does it take longer to call a fork() than it does to call pthread_create()?

Tags: pthreads, fork, createprocess

I was wondering this, is it because they only need a stack and storage for registers so they are cheap to create ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fork()` has to **clone** the entire process and all its associated kernel data structures, including file handles, memory, and so forth. Though this might be done lazily by setting appropriate copy-on-write flags, it is a lot more work than creating a new thread, which just **shares** the same file handles and memory.